# Download multiple files simultaneously (parallel) with custom filenames

Tags: bash, curl, wget, aria2

In a bash script, I am trying to download multiple files **in parallel**, with **custom filenames** using **a single** command (no loops).

I tried using aria2c:

```
aria2c -j2 URL1 URL2                # BAD: outputs to a single file

aria2c -j2 -Z URL1 -o 1 URL2 -o 2   # BAD: filenames taken from link (-o is ignored)
```

The second one ignores the output filename because, quoting the  aria2c manpage:

> In Metalink or BitTorrent download you cannot specify file name.  The file name  specified  here
>   is  only  used  when  the  URIs  fed  to  aria2  are  done by command line without --input-file,                 --force-sequential option. For example:
>
> $ aria2c -o myfile.zip "http://example1.com/file.zip" "http://example2.com/file.zip"

This is what I want to avoid:

```
aria2c URL1 -o 1 &
aria2c URL2 -o 2 &
aria2c URL3 -o 3                     # BAD: slow and ugly, because aria2c is called thrice
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What makes you believe multiple invocations is slow?

Comment: Alternatively, you can download the files and then rename them. However, input file allows you to specify the names of output files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Aria2c supports getting URIs from a file](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id2).

Try writing your file names into the file and then running "aria2c -i uri-list.txt" or write them to stdout and pipe them to "aria2c -i -"

Comment: Problem is that my URL's contain variables.

Comment: Do you mean shell variables? You can still use -i. Something like this:  # (echo "http://foo/bar/file-$VAR1.txt"; echo "http://bar/baz/file-$VAR2.txt") | aria2c -i -

Comment: While aria2c -i- is good, how do you end the input. I tried Ctrl+D but it doesn't end it as far as I see.

Answer (score 26):

with -Z option:

```
-Z, --force-sequential[=true|false] Fetch URIs in the command-line sequentially and download each URI in a separate session, like the usual command-line download utilities.
```

so in your case:

```
aria2c -Z URL1 URL2 URL3 URL4
```

Comment: This answers the question better IMO.

Comment: But why is this needed?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa I think because it by default considers the URLs to be multiple sources for the same file

Comment: Because `--force-sequential=false` is the default.